Hot reload not working in flutter on andriod emulator but working on Chrome (web)
When i save the code the hot reload works when i'm running the code Chrome (web) but it does not work when I run the code on an virtual andriod emulator such as Pixel 7A. Can anyone explain why?
Thanks,
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    Text('?n ?nm \n hello the hot reload works',
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    // textScaleFactor: 3,
    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
    // softWrap: true,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0, 
       // backgroundColor : Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      // color: Colors.blue,
      foreground: Paint()
      ..color = Colors.yellow
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..style =PaintingStyle.fill,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
      shadows: [
        Shadow(color: Colors.black, offset: Offset(2.0,1.0), blurRadius: 1.0)
      ]
    ),
    )
  );
}


Here is the code:
I was expecting the code to hot reload when i saved the code but it did not work

Hot reload  doesn't rerun main() or initState().  https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/hot-reload

Does this answer your question? Flutter web does "hot restart" instead of "hot reload". Is "hot reload" supported on flutter web?

Because hot reload hasn't supported Flutter web. Check here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/faq#does-hot-reload-work-with-a-web-app
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53041

